# Power Pivot: Relationship does not hold any data because it needs to be recalculated

Tags: powerpivot, dax

I have a relationship between a `Table1` table and a `Calendar` table.

When I try to use a DAX expression using fields from these table, I get this error:

The expression referenced a relationship between `Table1[DateKey]` and `CalendarTable[DateKey]`, which does not hold any data because it needs to be recalculated.

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your excel workbook (and Power Pivot) is most likely in manual calculation mode. Go to Power Pivot -> Design Tab -> Calculation Options -> "Automatic Calculation Mode". That will allow all your DAX fields to recalculate and the issue should be corrected.